# Wrong output on c++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

I am fairly new to C++ so this question may seem very basic(dumb!). I am trying to return an array of (int i, int j) which is a position(coordinates).

Here is my code:

```
int* Unblocker(int d1[2],int d2[2])
{
int unblocker_position[2];
int distance;
distance = abs(d1[0]-d2[0])+ abs(d1[1]-d2[1]);
switch (distance)
{
case 1:
    break;
case 2:
    switch (abs(d1[0] - d2[0]))
    {
    case 2:
        unblocker_position[0] = 1;
        unblocker_position[1] = 0;
        return unblocker_position;
        break;
    default:
        return NULL;
        break;
    }
    break;
default:
    return NULL;
    break;
}
}

int main(){
   int p1[2]={0,0};
   int p2[2]={2,0};
   int * a = Unblocker(p1,p2);
   cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << endl;
   return 0;}
```

The output is:

```
  1 1
```

however, I expect "1 0". I am not sure if I made a mistake using a switch or in using an array as the return type. I removed other cases in the switch to make it easier to get to the point.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable is **undefined behavior**. Also, there is no `return` statement executed if `distance` is 1, which is also **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Perfect! so I just needed to define unblocker_position as global. Thanks, @RemyLebeau!

Comment: You would avoid it (the local variable return part) if you used [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Or [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). Or a simple user-defined 2-element struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a pointer to a local variable you need to store the variable in the heap. To do so you have to use the `new` operator.

```
int *Unblocker(int d1[2], int d2[2])
{
    int *unblocker_position = new int[2];
    int distance;
    distance = abs(d1[0] - d2[0]) + abs(d1[1] - d2[1]);
    switch (distance)
    {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (abs(d1[0] - d2[0]))
        {
        case 2:
            unblocker_position[0] = 1;
            unblocker_position[1] = 0;
            return unblocker_position;
            break;
        default:
            return NULL;
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return NULL;
        break;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int p1[2] = {0, 0};
    int p2[2] = {2, 0};
    int *a = Unblocker(p1, p2);
    cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << endl;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to use the delete operator to prevent memory leaks.

If you want to learn more about this topic I suggest you look at [smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-160).